# Runtime error: Execution failed: Runtime panicked: Bad input data provided to validate_transaction: Invalid length prefix

Tags: pallet, rpc, golang, go-substrate-rpc-client

Getting Error :  "Verification Error: Runtime error: Execution failed: Runtime panicked: Bad input data provided to validate_transaction: Invalid length prefix" While calling the custom RPC method in substrate using golang centrifuge rpc client.

Custom Pallet Method

```
#[pallet::weight(10000)]
    pub fn post_single(
        origin: OriginFor<T>,
        amount: <<T as Config>::Currency as Currency<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>>::Balance,
        ) -> DispatchResult {
        let author = ensure_signed(origin)?;
                
        
         T::Currency::deposit_creating(
            &author,
            amount
        );
    

        Self::deposit_event(Event::PostTransaction(author));

        Ok(())
    }
```

Code from glang

```
    func Example_makeASimpleTransfer() {
        // Instantiate the API
        api, err := gsrpc.NewSubstrateAPI(config.Default().RPCURL)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    
        meta, err := api.RPC.State.GetMetadataLatest()
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    
    
        bal, ok := new(big.Int).SetString("100000000000000", 10)
        if !ok {
            panic(fmt.Errorf("failed to convert balance"))
        }
    
    
        c, err := types.NewCall(meta, "Ntxn.post_single",types.NewUCompact(bal))
        if err != nil {   
          panic(err)
        }   
         ........
_, err = api.RPC.Author.SubmitExtrinsic(ext)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Substrate node has panic error.

> Version: 4.0.0-dev-71cad6ec672
>
> 0: sp_panic_handler::set::{{closure}}    1:
> std::panicking::rust_panic_with_hook
> at /rustc/897e37553bba8b42751c67658967889d11ecd120/library/std/src/panicking.rs:702:17
> 2: std::panicking::begin_panic_handler::{{closure}}
> at /rustc/897e37553bba8b42751c67658967889d11ecd120/library/std/src/panicking.rs:588:13
> 3: std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_end_short_backtrace
> at /rustc/897e37553bba8b42751c67658967889d11ecd120/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:138:18
> 4: rust_begin_unwind
> at /rustc/897e37553bba8b42751c67658967889d11ecd120/library/std/src/panicking.rs:584:5
> 5: core::panicking::panic_fmt
> at /rustc/897e37553bba8b42751c67658967889d11ecd120/library/core/src/panicking.rs:142:14
> 6: node_template_runtime::api::dispatch    7:
> std::thread::local::LocalKey::with    8:
> sc_executor::native_executor::WasmExecutor::with_instance::{{closure}}
> 9: sc_executor::wasm_runtime::RuntimeCache::with_instance   10:
> <sc_executor::native_executor::NativeElseWasmExecutor as
> sp_core::traits::CodeExecutor>::call   11:
> sp_state_machine::execution::StateMachine<B,H,Exec>::execute_aux   12:
> sp_state_machine::execution::StateMachine<B,H,Exec>::execute_using_consensus_failure_handler
> 13: <sc_service::client::call_executor::LocalCallExecutor<Block,B,E>
> as sc_client_api::call_executor::CallExecutor>::contextual_call
> 14: <sc_service::client::client::Client<B,E,Block,RA> as
> sp_api::CallApiAt>::call_api_at   15:
> <node_template_runtime::RuntimeApiImpl<**SR_API_BLOCK**,RuntimeApiImplCall> as
> sp_finality_grandpa::GrandpaApi<**SR_API_BLOCK**>>::__runtime_api_internal_call_api_at
> 16:
> sp_transaction_pool::runtime_api::TaggedTransactionQueue::validate_transaction
> 17: tracing::span::Span::in_scope   18:
> sc_transaction_pool::api::validate_transaction_blocking   19:
> core::future::from_generator::GenFuture<T as
> core::future::future::Future>::poll   20:
> core::future::from_generator::GenFuture<T as
> core::future::future::Future>::poll   21:
> <futures_util::future::future::Map<Fut,F> as
> core::future::future::Future>::poll   22:
> <sc_service::task_manager::prometheus_future::PrometheusFuture as
> core::future::future::Future>::poll   23:
> core::future::from_generator::GenFuture<T as
> core::future::future::Future>::poll   24:
> tokio::runtime::context::BlockingRegionGuard::block_on   25:
> tokio::runtime::handle::Handle::block_on   26:
> tokio::runtime::blocking::task::BlockingTask<T as
> core::future::future::Future>::poll

As I am new to substrate and Rust not able to identify the issue. Please help how I need to pass the balance value. Seems that is the problem here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is difficult do debug any of your issue without source code.
However, it could be just the way that you are passing the balance.
Instead of `types.NewUCompact` you can try `types.U128`. The exact type depends on your runtime config, but the default would be `U128`, which has worked for me in the past as well.

If this does not solve your issue then please provide the code, thanks.

Comment: Thanks Its working when changed the types.